# Sticky Navigation Jumps to Top on Responsive

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, nav

[Here is a pen](http://codepen.io/taniarascia/pen/yNrwRb). I also have a [live version](http://www.taniarascia.com/primitive/stickynav.html).

I created a responsive nav with dropdowns, and everything works perfectly. I was working on making it sticky, as in after you scroll past a certain point, it becomes fixed to the top.

It works fine, except when you resize the page until the responsive hamburger menu shows up and click on it. The page then jumps to the top.

Here's my code for the sticky.

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
  if ($(window).scrollTop() >= $("header").height() + 30) {
    $(".sticky").addClass("fixed");
    $(".content").addClass("margin");

  } else {
    $(".sticky").removeClass("fixed");
    $(".content").removeClass("margin");
  }
});
```

And here's my css where the hamburger lives.

```
.nav-mobile {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: #efefef;
  height: 70px;
  width: 70px;
}
```

And here is the code for the navbar.

```
<section class="navigation sticky">
  <div class="nav-container">
    <div class="brand">
      <a href="index.html">Primitive</a>
    </div>
    <nav>
      <div class="nav-mobile"><a id="nav-toggle" href="#"><span></span></a></div>
      <ul class="nav-list">
        <li>
          <a href="index.html">Home</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</section>
```

Nothing has a fixed height outside of the `sticky` class.

Thanks!

Comment: The `#` tacked onto the url is sending the page back to the top. Use something like `e.stopPropagation()`, and add the event to the main function: `.scroll(function(e){}`

Comment: That did it! Thank you so much!

Comment: @yak613 Shouldn't it be `e.preventDefault()`?

Comment: Actually, it wasn't that - it was changing # to #! - this prevented the octothorpe from going anywhere. But he pointed me in the right direction!

Comment: @acbabis, yes it should. Good point.

Comment: @TaniaRascia I didn't know about that trick. Is it standard?

Comment: @acabis Yes, as far as I know. It basically performs a javscript(void) as far as I can tell. It certainly worked in my case!

Comment: You should actually resolve this with an answer so people can get rep and such...and so people like me don't think it's still unanswered. :)

Comment: @BenVisness The question can't be answered because the relevant code isn't in the question. It needs to be [edited to contain an MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or closed.

Comment: @acbabis Ah yes, you're right. But it still should be wrapped up somehow.

Comment: @BenVisness I added an answer and fixed my question, so hopefully it pertains to the guidelines and helps someone else in the future.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the fixed code.

```
<section class="navigation sticky">
  <div class="nav-container">
    <div class="brand">
      <a href="index.html">Primitive</a>
    </div>
    <nav>
      <div class="nav-mobile"><a id="nav-toggle" href="#!"><span></span></a></div>
      <ul class="nav-list">
        <li>
          <a href="index.html">Home</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</section>
```

To prevent an action happening on click toggle, add `href="#!"` to the `a` tag. Now the screen no longer jumps to the top when I click on the hamburger nav.